# Spring Velocity Exception while loading applicatonContext

Tags: spring, velocity

We use spring, velocity for email piece of code in our application and i got below exception. Any idea to solve this.

```
 "org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean' to required type 
'org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine' for property 'velocityEngine'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 
[org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean] to required type [org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine] for property 'velocityEngine': no matching editors or conversion strategy found "
```

Following is my context configuration.

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="xxxx.US"/>
    <property name="port" value="25"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">false</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">false</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="velocityProperties">
        <value>
            resource.loader=class
            class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader       
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="emailUtil" class="com.example.MailUtil">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" /> 
    <property name="velocityEngine" ref="velocityEngine" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to reference the velocityEngine in your emailUtil bean. Everything else about your spring config is correct.

I grabbed the following code from my app to show you how we are able to use velocity templates.

```
private String generateMessageFromTemplate(User user, VelocityTemplateEnum velocityTemplateEnum) {
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    context.put("user", user);
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    String template = velocityTemplateDao.findById(velocityTemplateEnum.name()).getTemplate();
    Velocity.evaluate(context, stringWriter, velocityTemplateEnum.name(), template);
    return stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup only I autowire in the VelocityEngine and that's working for me. Is autowiring an option for you? Also, can you add the code for your MailUtil class? Maybe something isn't 100% right with the velocityEngine field/setter?